# apply function to grouped rows in dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I have created a function that computes a number of biological statistics, such as species range edges. Here is a simplified version of the function:

```
range_stats <- function(rangedf, lat, lon, weighting, na.rm=T){
  cent_lat <- weighted.mean(x=rangedf[,lat], w=rangedf[,weighting], na.rm=T)
  cent_lon <- weighted.mean(x=rangedf[,lon], w=rangedf[,weighting], na.rm=T)
out <- data.frame(cent_lat, cent_lon)    
return(out)
}
```

I would like to apply this to a large dataframe where every row is an observation of a species. As such, I want the function to group rows by a specified set of columns, and then computer these statistics for each group. Here is a test dataframe:

```
LATITUDE <- c(27.91977, 21.29066, 26.06340, 28.38918, 25.97517, 27.96313)
LONGITUDE <- c(-175.8617, -157.8645, -173.9593, -178.3571, -173.9679, -175.7837)
BIOMASS <- c(4.3540488, 0.2406332, 0.2406332, 2.1419699, 0.3451426, 1.0946017)
SPECIES <- c('Abudefduf abdominalis','Abudefduf abdominalis','Abudefduf abdominalis','Chaetodon lunulatus','Chaetodon lunulatus','Chaetodon lunulatus')
YEAR <- c('2005', '2005', '2014', '2009', '2009', '2015')
testdf <- data.table(LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, BIOMASS, SPECIES, YEAR)
```

I want to apply this function to every unique combination of species and year to calculate summary statistics, i.e., the following:

```
testresult <- testdf %>%
  group_by(SPECIES, YEAR) %>%
  range_stats(lat="LATITUDE",lon="LONGITUDE",weighting="BIOMASS",na.rm=T)
```

However, the code above does not work (I get a `(list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'` error) and I am not sure how else to approach the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you add the tag of `dplyr` and `purrr`, I assume you are interested in a `tidyverse` solution. So below I will demonstrate a solution based on the `tidyverse`.

First, your `range_stats` is problematic. This is why you got the error message. The `weighted.mean` is expecting a vector for both the `x` and `w` argument. However, if `rangedf` is a `tibble`, the way you subset the `tibble`, such as `rangedf[,lat]` will still return a one-column `tibble`. A better way is to use `pull` from the `dplyr` package.

```
library(tidyverse)
range_stats <- function(rangedf, lat, lon, weighting, na.rm=T){
  cent_lat <- weighted.mean(x = rangedf %>% pull(lat), 
                            w = rangedf %>% pull(weighting), na.rm=T)
  cent_lon <- weighted.mean(x = rangedf %>% pull(lon), 
                            w = rangedf %>% pull(weighting), na.rm=T)
  out <- data.frame(cent_lat, cent_lon)    
  return(out)
}
```

Next, the way you created the data frame is OK, but `data.table` is from the `data.table` package and you will create a `data.table`, not a `tibble`. I thought you want to use an approach from `tidyverse`, so I changed `data.table` to `data_frame` as follows.

```
LATITUDE <- c(27.91977, 21.29066, 26.06340, 28.38918, 25.97517, 27.96313)
LONGITUDE <- c(-175.8617, -157.8645, -173.9593, -178.3571, -173.9679, -175.7837)
BIOMASS <- c(4.3540488, 0.2406332, 0.2406332, 2.1419699, 0.3451426, 1.0946017)
SPECIES <- c('Abudefduf abdominalis','Abudefduf abdominalis','Abudefduf abdominalis','Chaetodon lunulatus','Chaetodon lunulatus','Chaetodon lunulatus')
YEAR <- c('2005', '2005', '2014', '2009', '2009', '2015')
testdf <- data_frame(LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, BIOMASS, SPECIES, YEAR)
```

Now, you said you want to apply the `range_stats` function to each combination of `SPECIES` and `YEAR`. One approach is to split the data frame to a list of data frames, and use `lapply` family function. But here I want to show you how to use the `map` family function to achieve this task as `map` is from the `purrr` package, which is part of the `tidyverse`.

We can first create a group indices based on `SPECIES` and `YEAR`.

```
testdf2 <- testdf %>%
  mutate(Group = group_indices(., SPECIES, YEAR)) 
testdf2
# A tibble: 6 x 6
  LATITUDE LONGITUDE   BIOMASS               SPECIES  YEAR Group
     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>                 <chr> <chr> <int>
1 27.91977 -175.8617 4.3540488 Abudefduf abdominalis  2005     1
2 21.29066 -157.8645 0.2406332 Abudefduf abdominalis  2005     1
3 26.06340 -173.9593 0.2406332 Abudefduf abdominalis  2014     2
4 28.38918 -178.3571 2.1419699   Chaetodon lunulatus  2009     3
5 25.97517 -173.9679 0.3451426   Chaetodon lunulatus  2009     3
6 27.96313 -175.7837 1.0946017   Chaetodon lunulatus  2015     4
```

As you can see, `Group` is a new column showing the index number. Now we can split the data frame based on `Group`, and then use `map_dfr` to apply the `range_stats` function.

```
testresult <- testdf2 %>%
  split(.$Group) %>%
  map_dfr(range_stats, lat = "LATITUDE",lon = "LONGITUDE", 
          weighting = "BIOMASS", na.rm = TRUE, .id = "Group")
testresult
  Group cent_lat  cent_lon
1     1 27.57259 -174.9191
2     2 26.06340 -173.9593
3     3 28.05418 -177.7480
4     4 27.96313 -175.7837
```

Notice that `map_dfr` can automatic bind the output list of data frames to a single data frame. `.id = "Group"` means we want to create a column called `Group` based on the name of the list element.

I separated the process into two steps, but of course they can be all in one pipeline as follows.

```
testresult  <- testdf %>%
  mutate(Group = group_indices(., SPECIES, YEAR))  %>%
  split(.$Group) %>%
  map_dfr(range_stats, lat = "LATITUDE",lon = "LONGITUDE", 
          weighting = "BIOMASS", na.rm = TRUE, .id = "Group")
```

If you want, `testresult` can be merged with `testdf` using `left_join`, but I will stop here as `testresult` is probably already the desired output you want. I hope this helps.

Comment: Perfect solution, thank you! I implemented it exactly, except rather than `mutate(Group = group_indices(., SPECIES, YEAR))`, I used a meaningful column name so that the identifier in the output df makes sense: `mutate(GROUPID = paste(YEAR, SPECIES))`.

Comment: @AFH Nice way to create meaningful Group Name or ID. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally, the main issue involves `weighted.mean()` where you are passing a dataframe object and not a vector that can be coerced to double. To fix within method, simply change:

```
x=rangedf[,lat]
```

To double brackets:

```
x=rangedf[[lat]]
```

Adjusted method:

```
range_stats <- function(rangedf, lat, lon, weighting, na.rm=T){
  cent_lat <- weighted.mean(x=rangedf[[lat]], w=rangedf[[weighting]], na.rm=T)
  cent_lon <- weighted.mean(x=rangedf[[lon]], w=rangedf[[weighting]], na.rm=T)
  out <- data.frame(cent_lat, cent_lon)    
  return(out)
}
```

---

As for overall group by slice computation, do forgive me in bypassing, `dplyr` and `data.table` which you use and consider base R's underutilized but useful method, `by()`.

The challenge with your current setup is the output of *range_stats* method return is a data.frame of two columns and dplyr's `group_by()` expects one aggregation vector operation. However, `by` passes dataframe objects (sliced by factors) into a defined function to return a list of data.frames which you can then `rbind` for one final dataframe:

```
df_List <- by(testdf, testdf[, c("SPECIES", "YEAR")], FUN=function(df)
                data.frame(species=df$SPECIES[1],
                           year=df$YEAR[1],
                           range_stats(df,"LATITUDE","LONGITUDE","BIOMASS"))
              )

finaldf <- do.call(rbind, df_List)
finaldf
#                 species year cent_lat  cent_lon
# 1 Abudefduf abdominalis 2005 27.57259 -174.9191
# 2   Chaetodon lunulatus 2009 28.05418 -177.7480
# 3 Abudefduf abdominalis 2014 26.06340 -173.9593
# 4   Chaetodon lunulatus 2015 27.96313 -175.7837
```